# How do you... Define a Graphing Function

Tags: python, plotly, data-analysis

*For Data Analytics & using Python*. I came across this code(below) and my question is... did the user copy and paste this from somewhere or **do I define a graphing function from scratch**??????

Using plotly (first time using plotly)

Very new to Python

```
def make_graph(stock_data, revenue_data, stock):
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, subplot_titles=("Historical Share Price", "Historical Revenue"), vertical_spacing = .3)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(stock_data.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=stock_data.Close.astype("float"), name="Share Price"), row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(revenue_data.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=revenue_data.Revenue.astype("float"), name="Revenue"), row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Price ($US)", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Revenue ($US Millions)", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False,
    height=900,
    title=stock,
    xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)
    fig.show()
```

Comment: It is just a function of graphing. [Here is the official reference.](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#time-series-with-range-slider) Please refer to it.

Comment: i read your question but don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question Lei, I'm lacking a lot of knowledge in this field so my questions might be kinda vague while I'm trying my best to not be vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you are wondering where functions and methods inside the `make_graph` function are coming from – some import statements might clear things up for you:

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def make_graph(stock_data, revenue_data, stock):
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, subplot_titles=("Historical Share Price", "Historical Revenue"), vertical_spacing = .3)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(stock_data.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=stock_data.Close.astype("float"), name="Share Price"), row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(revenue_data.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=revenue_data.Revenue.astype("float"), name="Revenue"), row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Price ($US)", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Revenue ($US Millions)", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False,
    height=900,
    title=stock,
    xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)
    fig.show()
```

When you call the function `make_graph`, it uses the Plotly library's [make_subplots](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/) function to create an object `fig` which is a [Plotly graph object](https://plotly.com/python/graph-objects/). All graph objects (such as `fig`) have the methods `add_trace`, `update_xaxes`, `update_yaxes`, `update_layout`, and `show` (as well as other methods) which can be called using dot notation.

The last line `fig.show()` will use a default renderer (e.g. your browser) to display the figure.

Your textbook very likely includes some sample code to call the `make_graph` function. I think running this function and looking at the output may help clear things up for you as well.

Comment: Very thorough with the information and I understand what is actually happening now, thank you!!